# SVG donut with colored segments and clock animation

Tags: css-animations, svg-animate

I'm new to SVG and trying to familiarize myself with it. I would like to create a SVG donut with several segments each segments with different color. It's important that the segments should be interactive (meaning if I hover over them they should change color or pop out). The whole donut should appear with a clock animation.

I tried this with a simple circle and set the `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` accordingly. The donut appears properly but when I apply the clock animation with CSS it overrides the color of all segments to the color of the last segment. But then I was thinking about if I want each segment to be interactive probably I have to create a `circle` svg element for each segment or a create svg `arc`s and build my donut that way.

I would appreciate any advice which way should I go. Here's my code so far:

**HTML:**

```
 <svg id = "circleMenuViewBox" width = "100%" height = "100%" viewBox="-10 -10 100 100">
    <defs>
      <circle id ="circlemenu" cx="10" cy="10" r="5" stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="31.4"/>
      </defs>
      <use href="#circlemenu" stroke="#689689" stroke-dashoffset="0"/>
      <use href="#circlemenu" stroke="#83E8BA" stroke-dashoffset="7.85"/>
      <use href="#circlemenu" stroke="#B2E6D4" stroke-dashoffset="15.7"/>
      <use href="#circlemenu" stroke="#504136" stroke-dashoffset="23.55"/>
    </svg>
```

**CSS:**

```
#circlemenu { 
 fill: none;
 stroke-dasharray: 31.4;
 stroke-dashoffset: 31.4;
 animation: clock-animation 0.2s linear;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes clock-animation {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 31.4;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animation is causing the last circle to overlay all other segments.

Instead of animating the circle definition referenced by all `<use>` instances you can create a `<mask>` to progressively show the donut chart.

```css
#circleMask { 
 fill: none;
 stroke-dasharray: 31.4;
 stroke-dashoffset: 31.4;
 animation: clock-animation 0.8s linear;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes clock-animation {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 31.4;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="circleMenuViewBox" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-10 -10 100 100">
  <defs>
    <circle id="circlemenu" cx="10" cy="10" r="5" stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="31.4" />
    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <use id="circleMask" class="segment" href="#circlemenu" stroke="#fff" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#mask)">
  <use class="segment" href="#circlemenu" stroke="#689689" stroke-dashoffset="0" />
  <use class="segment" href="#circlemenu" stroke="#83E8BA" stroke-dashoffset="7.85" />
  <use class="segment" href="#circlemenu" stroke="#B2E6D4" stroke-dashoffset="15.7" />
  <use class="segment" href="#circlemenu" stroke="#504136" stroke-dashoffset="23.55" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you @herrstrietzel! I appreciate your quick response. This solved the problem. I'll look after how to use masks because I have never used them before.

Comment: Kind of an off topic but is there any way to trigger this masked animation on a right mouse click? I tried to add/remove the mask and the class of the <mask> and  <g> elements through JavaScript without any luck.

Comment: You can  use a transition instead to change the stroke offset and toggle classes. `.showMenu #circleMask { stroke-dashoffset: 0;}` See [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/GRPNpaR)

Comment: Thanks a million @herrstrietzel! I really appreciate your help. I need to deep dive into SVG because there's so many potential in it. If you have any source on this topic that is worth to read / watch to an SVG newbie please let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: You'll definitely find a lot of solution/methods searching for SO questions related to charts, donut charts progress gauges etc.

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this but I'm traying to re-trigger the animation through JavaScript in case of a right-mouse click. I found several articles and post on this topic but none of them seems to work. I looked after what events can re-trigger the SVG flow and I found for example 'instanceRoot' can do this but it's not working.  In theory I remove the 'showMenu' Class by using classList.remove() then initiate 'instanceroot' and then adding the 'showMenu' class again through JavaScript but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea?